# A problem of forming equal angles in plane geometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

$C$ and $D$ are two points on the same side of a straight line $AB$. Find a point $X$ on $AB$ such that $\angle CXA = \angle DXB$.

Comment: do you want a geometrical construction or a way on how to calculate the coordinates of X given the coordinates of the others?

Comment: @Willemien I want geometrical explanation.

Comment: geometrical explanation is not an useful concept, do you wwant an construction ( get your ruler and compass) or a coordinate (get out your caculator)

Comment: @Willemien As you insist, You better give Geometrical Construction.

Answer (score 1):

then construct it as

- draw line d  perpendicular to AB line from D
- E is the intersection of line d and AB
- draw circle C1, centre at E trough D
- F is the intersection of  C1 and line d
- draw line e  between C and F
- the intersection of e and AB is point X